# How to creat a .md file in github?

Tags: github, markdown

I want to create a .md file in github .So I use Markdown format .But when I eidted.I check the preview,and there still have "##".And I don't how to slove this ?
[image: origina format]
[image: result format]

Comment: Will you give a link to the uploaded `README.md`?

Comment: it would be only # Helloworld

Comment: not  a REAME.md  but a new markdown format file.And this is my file: https://github.com/2629743986/StudyNote/blob/master/java/javaSE/Enum.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at your markdown file. You have a syntax error. A space characer is needed after ##.

Comment: Thank you,With your help,I solved this problem.And I also find that we must eidt like this"## HelloWord" "##" and "HelloWord" shold have a space

Comment: Yup, need a space!